# Change dictionary from finnish-czech to czech finnish

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have this file http://sinivalkoiset.wz.cz/ostatni/finnish-czech.txt
and I would like to swap first collumn with the second one. I used the sed commend

```
sed -ne 's/\([^a-z A-Z].*\) \(.*\)$/\2 \1/ p' finnish-czech.txt
```

Second backreference works but the first one doesn't. I used as the end of backreference the 'space'. But then I realised it wouldn't work like that, because some words contains two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words in different languges are separated by tabs, not spaces. Sed doesn't handle tabs, but you can use `$'\t'` in bash:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)'$'\t''\(.*\)/\2'$'\t''\1/' finnish-czech.txt
```

Before doing so, though, remove the Windows line endings from the file by running `dos2unix` or `fromdos` on it.

Comment: Why does sed not handle tabs? Try `sed -e 's/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\2\t\1/' < <(printf "abc\tdef")`

Comment: @Lambert: IIRC, some sed implementations don't.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest `awk`?

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} {sub(/\r/, ""); print $2,$1}' finnish-czech.txt
```

And this will get rid of the Windows carriage returns in your file, too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your file has Windows-style line endings. That can confuse things. Also, it has some extra characters at the beginning:

```
$ wget -O - http://sinivalkoiset.wz.cz/ostatni/finnish-czech.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n1 | od -c
0000000 357 273 277   A   f   r   i   k   k   a  \t   A   f   r   i   k
0000020   a  \r  \n
0000023
```

In any case, if you\re not too tied to `sed`, this sort of thing is very easy with `awk`:

```
tr -d $'\r'  < finnish-czech.txt | awk -F"\t" -vOFS="\t" '{print $2,$1}'
```

The `tr` removes `\r` and then the awk will print the 2nd field followed by the 1st. The `-F"\t"` sets the input field separator to tab (this isn't needed unless you can have more than 2 words per line) and the `-vOFS=:\t"` sets the output separator to tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern grouping to capture the columns and then swap them in replacement:

```
sed 's/^\([^[:blank:]]\+\)\([[:blank:]]\+\)\([^[:blank:]]\+\).*/\3\2\1/' file.txt
```